# Compare encrypted values

Tags: encryption

Is there any way to make an encryption scheme where you can check whether two values were very similar by only looking at the encrypted values. By alike I mean something like 1113740 and 1123740 are alike. Ideal would if you could make something like a threshold distance in a normed space. Is this possible or will these demands inevitably break the encryption?

Comment: See format-preserving encryption, or encrypt each char one by one in ECB mode. Frequency information about the digits can break the confidentiality.

Comment: @kelalaka: format-preserving encryption isn't what he is looking for.  FPE is encryption where the encryption input and output aren't necessarily bit strings, but more general domains (such as a sequence of 7 decimal digits), and the format of the output is the same as the format of the input.  However, FPE does not leak the 'closeness' information that Emiel is asking about.

Comment: @poncho OP looks for a look-alike, so one can use deterministic FPE by fixing the IV, they can get it, however, the domain and range can be a problem.

Comment: To clarify, I ask this question purely out of curiosity. There was just a toy idea that occurred where you get encrypted GPS data and you are able to say which encrypted coordinates are close to each other.

Comment: I think you might be looking for _Order-Preserving Encryption_ or _Searchable Encryption_? Also what you're describing usually sounds like a case for _Secure Multi-Party Computation_?